# Is it more expensive to send a data structure to a function to just check its data than sending a pointer?

Tags: c, optimization

I have a struct with some data inside, I want to check this data in a function without editing anything inside the structure, so I can send the struct object to the function instead of sending a pointer to it. My question is, knowing that sending an object to a function creates a duplicate of the object local to the function, isn't it more expensive for memory than just passing a pointer to the initial object ? Especially if the structure contains a lot of data

```
typedef struct s_foo
{
  int data;
}              foo;

int function(foo object) // Is this one more expensive ?
{
  if (object.data == ...)
    return (...);
}

int function(const foo * object) // And this one less expensive ?
{
  if (object->data == ...)
    return (...);
}

int main(void)
{
  foo myobject;

  myobject.data = ...;
  if (function( (&)myobject ) == ...)
    do something;
  return (0);
}
```

Comment: It depends.  In general, if the data structure is smaller than the pointer then it is certainly more efficient to send it.  If not, it will depend on how much bigger than a pointer it is and how many times you dereference the pointer.

Comment: How "big" do you think `foo` is? It only contains one `int`. (You can check with `printf("%zu\n", sizeof(foo))`.) Is that larger or smaller than `sizeof(const foo *)`?

Comment: As a practical matter, don't even think about it until you have some benchmarks to say you should.  And then you'll know enough about it that you'll know what to do.

Comment: Use an optimizing compiler, profile your application, and find out. And if you change your code, profile it again. Any other answer is just a guess.